# Can Classes Use Assignment Unpacking Similar to Iterable Lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list `myList = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]` which I can use assignment unpacking to get `list_instance0, list_instance1, list_instance2 = myList`

If I have a class:

```
class myClass():
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: int):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
    def printAB(self):
        return self.a, self.b
```

Now If I want to assign the `list_instance[i]` I can do:

```
classInstance0=myClass(*list_instance0)
classInstance1=myClass(*list_instance1)
classInstance2=myClass(*list_instance2)
```

If I was to try

```
subClass0, subClass1, subClass2 = myClass(*list_instance0, *list_instance1, *list_instance2)
# error "myClass" is not iterable: __iter__ method not defined
```

So I was wondering is there a way to assign `classInstance[i]` with `list_instance[i]` to `myClass` in a more dynamic way instead of having to assign each one individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply want to map `MyClass` over your list.

```
from itertools import starmap

subClass0, subClass1, subClass2 = starmap(myClass, myList)
```

`starmap` ensures the *contents* of each sublist are passed as separate arguments to `myClass`, rather than the sublist itself passed as a single argument.

or you can use a list comprehension to be a little more explicit:

```
subClass0, subClass1, subClass2 = [myClass(*x) for x in myList]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. To be honest, off the top of my head I don't believe there is a way to automatically deconstruct sub-lists into a class instance.

Something like below, I don't know that it works in Python:

```
MyClass(*subList0), MyClass(*subList1), MyClass(*subList2) = myList
```

I would suggest defining a helper class method, `from_list`, to automatically create an iterable of class objects, given a list of lists `my_list`:

```py
@classmethod
def from_list(cls, super_list: list[list[int]]) -> Iterable[MyClass]:
    for sub_list in super_list:
        yield cls(*sub_list)
```

Complete usage, using the [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) module for better output when a class instance is `print`ed out, would be as follows:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Iterable


@dataclass
class MyClass:
    a: int
    b: int

    def printAB(self):
        return self.a, self.b

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, super_list: list[list[int]]) -> Iterable[MyClass]:
        for sub_list in super_list:
            try:
                yield cls(*sub_list)
            except TypeError:
                raise ValueError(f'value `{sub_list}` @ index={super_list.index(sub_list)}: '
                                 f'expected 2 elements, got {len(sub_list)}') from None


my_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

# alternatively:
#   for sc in MyClass.from_list(my_list):
#       print(sc)

subClass0, subClass1, subClass2 = MyClass.from_list(my_list)

print(subClass0)
print(subClass1)
print(subClass2)
```

Output:

```
MyClass(a=1, b=2)
MyClass(a=3, b=4)
MyClass(a=5, b=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding inheritance. The items you are calling sublcass are not *subclasses* of myClass. They are *instances* of myClass. So the short answer is no. Calling the constructor for myClass returns a single object. Namely, an instance of myClass. So it cannot be assigned to 3 objects or an iterable, because it returns a single object.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single call to the `myClass` constructor return three instances of `myClass` doesn't make sense (you might technically be able to do this by doing weird things with `__new__`, but don't).  What you want instead, I think, is some kind of factory function that takes a list of init args and gives you a list of instances, since you can then destructure that the way you want.  For example:

```
def my_class_factory(*init_args):
    return [myClass(*args) for args in init_args]

subClass0, subClass1, subClass2 = my_class_factory(subList0, subList1, subList2)  # works
subClass0, subClass1, subClass2 = my_class_factory(*myList)  # also works!
```

Note that the variables you're calling `subClass` *are not subclasses*, they are *instances* of `myClass`.